# How to fetch the title of a Joomla article?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have designed a Joomla template. I want to bring my articles on my template, I have written code that is bring article body text on my template but neither image nor title is coming up. Can anyone help please ?

```
$query = "select * from jh7na_content order by id desc limit 2";
$sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<div id='div1' style='border='2px';'>".html_entity_decode($row['introtext'])."</div>";             
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things you should know. Firstly, if you want to show an article, why not create a menu item, and assign an article to it in the Joomla backend? Secondly, your query is only showing the article text because you have told it to and are not calling the Title. Thirdly, you should be using Joomla coding standards, especially when making database queries, like so:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*')
 ->from('#__content')
 ->order('id DESC');
$db->setQuery($query,0,2);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach($rows as $row){
    echo "<div class='title'>" . $row['title']. "</div>"; 
    echo "<div class='introtext'>" . $row['introtext']. "</div>"; 
}
```

However, as stated before, you should assign an article to a menu item.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are only echoing the intro text and not the title or the image, that would explain why the introtext and not the title or image is showing.  Look at the core layouts to see how to render each part of an article.

However, if you mean you have written an actual template, which in Joomla is used for design purposes, you should not be putting any specific code like this there, you would just be using a jdoc statement to include your article.

Do not reinvent the wheel. Joomla is a content management system, use it for content management. It will automatically load your content for you.  That's what it is totally designed to do -- take care of that part while you worry about content and design.  If you want to make a different appearing page than the core you can do a layout override (search for an answer on how to do that).  But I suggest first that you learn a bit about how Joomla works.  Open up the core code and study it, then you will know how to work with it.

Comment: then how can i bring latest articles in my theme between particular div

Comment: Put it in the div.  That div should be in the layout file for an article not in a template file.  The jdoc:include component can also be in a div. But that will be the general div for all components.   And remember the articles already have standard layouts with divs, classes and ids that you can use for your css. You only need to worry about new divs if you want to change the standard layout in some way that can't be done with css. Work with the core first and make sure you understand it, just spend an hour or two doing that and you will save 100s of hours of reinventing things.